# Python, store a dict in a database

Tags: python, string, dictionary

What's the best way to store and retrieve a python dict in a database?

Answer (score 19):

If you are not specifically interested into using a traditionally SQL database, such as MySQL, you could look into unstructured document databases where documents naturally map to python dictionaries, for example [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/). The MongoDB [python bindings](http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.6%2B/index.html) allow you to just insert dicts in the DB, and query them based on the values in the dict. See for example the code below:

```
import pymongo
myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
mydb=myclient["mydatabase"]
mycol = mydb["customers"]
mydict = { "name": "John", "address": "Highway 37" }
x = mycol.insert_one(mydict)
```

And to find the entry:

```
print(mycol.find_one({"name":"John"}))
```

Comment: heh, yeah it's pretty cool ;). I've recently started playing around with MongoDB and it's really quite nice since it's document model is based on Binary JSON. Since I'm sounding like a commercial here, heck there is even a free online hosting serivce (free for 16MB): https://mongohq.com/home :p

Comment: mongo at most store a dict of depth 100

Answer (score 6):

"Best" is debatable.
If you need a DBMS, sqlite is built in; so it might be considered an easier method than some of the other ways mentioned.

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("create table kv (key text, value integer);")
# <sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x00C62CE0>
d = {'a':1,'b':2}
c.executemany("insert into kv values (?,?);", d.iteritems())
# <sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x00C62CE0>
c.execute("select * from kv;").fetchall()
# [(u'a', 1), (u'b', 2)]
```

Answer (score 4):

Fairly vague question, depends a lot on the use cases.

Typically you'd just serialize it and insert it wherever it was needed, but if you need the dict itself to be "database-like", then you can use one of [many of the available key/value stores for Python](http://anyall.org/blog/2009/04/performance-comparison-keyvalue-stores-for-language-model-counts/)

Answer (score 4):

If the dict directly corresponds to a database table, then you should set up a table with a schema containing two columns - `key` and `value`. Then for each element of the dict, just insert it into the database, or update it if the key is already in place, etc.

Otherwise you could use [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) to serialize the dict to a string, and then you could just save the string to the DB. But in general I would not recommend this solution since you cannot query the serialized data.